$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\cos(x)\right)}}{\sin(x)}\;\mathrm{d}x}$
I am trying to solve this integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\cos(x)\right)}}{\sin(x)}\;\mathrm{d}x}$$
I know that it must have something to do with the Cin function:
$$\mathrm{Cin}(x)=\int_{0}^{x}{\frac{1-\cos(t)}{t}\;\mathrm{d}t}$$
but I can't get it to take this form.
The full solution (special thanks to @stoic-santiago):
$$\begin{align}\Gamma&=\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\cos(\vartheta)\right)}}{\sin(\vartheta)}\;\mathrm{d}\vartheta}=\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin(\vartheta)\cdot\frac{\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\cos(\vartheta)\right)}}{1-\cos^2(\vartheta)}\;\mathrm{d}\vartheta} \\
 &=\begin{bmatrix}
  u=\cos(\vartheta) & \\
  \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}\vartheta}=-\sin(\vartheta) & \mathrm{d}\vartheta=-\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sin(\vartheta)}
 \end{bmatrix}=-\int_{1}^{-1}{\frac{\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot u\right)}}{1-u^2}\;\mathrm{d}u} \\
 &=\left[\frac{1}{1-u^2}=\frac{1}{(1+u)(1-u)}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{1+u}+\frac{1}{1-u}\right)\right] \\
 &=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\int_{1}^{-1}{\frac{\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot u\right)}}{1+u}\;\mathrm{d}u}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\int_{1}^{-1}{\frac{\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot u\right)}}{1-u}\;\mathrm{d}u} \\
 &=\begin{bmatrix}
  t=1+u & \\
  \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}u}=1 & \mathrm{d}t=\mathrm{d}u
 \end{bmatrix}\;\text{and}\;\begin{bmatrix}
  v=1-u & \\
  \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u}=-1 & \mathrm{d}v=-\mathrm{d}u
 \end{bmatrix} \\
 &=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\int_{2}^{0}{\frac{\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot (t-1)\right)}}{t}\;\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\int_{0}^{2}{\frac{\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot (1-v)\right)}}{v}\;\mathrm{d}v} \\
 &=-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left[\int_{2}^{0}{\frac{2\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot (t-1)\right)}-1+1}{t}\;\mathrm{d}t}-\int_{0}^{2}{\frac{2\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot (1-v)\right)}-1+1}{v}\;\mathrm{d}v}\right] \\
 &=-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left[\int_{2}^{0}{\frac{\cos{\left(\pi\cdot (t-1)\right)}+1}{t}\;\mathrm{d}t}-\int_{0}^{2}{\frac{\cos{\left(\pi\cdot (1-v)\right)}+1}{v}\;\mathrm{d}v}\right] \\
 &=-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left[\int_{2}^{0}{\frac{1-\cos{(\pi t)}}{t}\;\mathrm{d}t}-\int_{0}^{2}{\frac{1-\cos{(\pi v)}}{v}\;\mathrm{d}v}\right] \\
 &=\begin{bmatrix}
  x=\pi t & \\
  \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=\pi & \mathrm{d}t=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\pi}
 \end{bmatrix}\;\text{and}\;\begin{bmatrix}
  y=\pi v & \\
  \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}v}=\pi & \mathrm{d}v=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\pi}
 \end{bmatrix} \\
 &=-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left[\int_{2\pi}^{0}{\frac{1-\cos{(x)}}{\frac{x}{\pi}}\;\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\pi}}-\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{1-\cos{(y)}}{\frac{y}{\pi}}\;\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\pi}}\right] \\
 &=-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left[\int_{2\pi}^{0}{\frac{1-\cos{(x)}}{x}\;\mathrm{d}x}-\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{1-\cos{(y)}}{y}\;\mathrm{d}y}\right] \\
 &=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left[\mathrm{Cin}(2\pi)+\mathrm{Cin}(2\pi)\right]=\frac{\mathrm{Cin}(2\pi)}{2}\end{align}$$

I think it is symmetric arount $x = \pi/2$, so perhaps a change of variables might help.

Not much of a help, I know, but the numerical value is:  $2.79716$.

Thank you both, I have just realised that a typo has accidentally crept in. The square in the denominator of the sine should not have been there. I was also able to determine the new numerical value using WolframAlpha: $1.21883$.

Just use https://www.integral-calculator.com/ it gives you the answer with Ci function.

Write  $$\int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\cos(x)\right)}}{\sin(x)}\;\mathrm{d}x} = \int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin x\cdot\frac{\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\cos(x)\right)}}{1-\cos^2(x)}\;\mathrm{d}x}.$$
With $u:= \cos x$, we get
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}{\sin x\cdot\frac{\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\cos(x)\right)}}{1-\cos^2(x)}\;\mathrm{d}x} = \int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi u}{2}\right)}}{1-u^2}\;\mathrm{d}u}.$$
As $$\frac{1}{1-u^2} = \frac{1}{(1+u)(1-u)} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{1+u} + \frac{1}{1-u}\right),$$ we can write
$$\int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi u}{2}\right)}}{1-u^2}\;\mathrm{d}u}= \frac 1 2 \int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi u}{2}\right)}}{1+u}\;\mathrm{d}u} + \frac12 \int_{-1}^{1}{\frac{\cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi u}{2}\right)}}{1-u}\;\mathrm{d}u}.$$
Use the substitution $y:= 1 + u$ for the first integral. For the second, use $z := 1 - u$. In both cases, use the formula $\cos 2\theta = 2 \cos^2\theta - 1 = 1-2\sin^2 \theta$ as necessary to reduce the exponent in the numerator. This should yield a result in terms of the $\operatorname{Cin}$ function.

Mathematica:  $\text{Si}(\pi )$

@stoic-santiago First of all, thank you very much, I didn't think of the decomposition with the fractions. But one more small question: Don't the integration limits change with the u-substitution? Or am i wrong here?

@FixFox You're right - I have made the edits. Thanks for pointing it out.

@FixFox The full solution in your edit looks good. Feel free to accept this answer if it helped. Cheers!
